# Issue with password in user login system. C#

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010

I have developed a web application in visual studio 2010 and am attempting to add a user login system to this application.  So far I am having trouble validating the users password, as the program informs me that all passwords are incorrect even if it matches the one associated to that username.  This is the code I have written son far:

```
    protected void n_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        con.Open();
        string cmdStr = "select count(*) from Registration where UserName='" + TextBoxUserName.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand CheckUser = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
        int Temp = Convert.ToInt32(CheckUser.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        if (Temp == 1)
        {
            string cmdStr2 = "Select Password from Registration where UserName ='" + TextBoxUserName.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand pass = new SqlCommand(cmdStr2, con);
            string password = pass.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            con.Close();

            if (password == TextBoxPassword.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = TextBoxUserName.Text;
                Response.Redirect("HomePage.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Visible = true;
                Label1.Text = "Password is invalid";
            }
        }
        else
        {
             Label1.Visible = true;
             Label1.Text = "Username is invalid";
        }


    }
}
```

}

Regardless of what password is entered the program will output 'password is invalid' which indicates that the issue is with the first part of the if statement? or the variables it uses?
It might also be worth mentioning that an invalid username flags up in the same way, and this works fine.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check SQL Injection - you have one.

Comment: Your passwords should be salted and hashed in the database; you should never store passwords in plaintext.

Comment: What you have so far looks incredibly insecure. Google "SQL injection attack" to see what I mean.

Comment: Look into [Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx).

Comment: Try replace `pass.ExecuteScalar().ToString()` 
with 

`(pass.ExecuteScalar()+"")`

You shouldnt use .ToString() with querys.

Comment: Really, storing the password clear-text in the database?  What site is this for so I can avoid using it...

Comment: ideally you shouldn't say whether a username exists or not on login.

Comment: Set a break point and see what value of *password* is being returned.

Comment: @Daniel - If you do don't indicate which one is invalid. As others pointed out there are lots of problems with this code security wise. If one where to indicate their username was '*' it would select all the usernames in the database.  This means they could brute force every single account at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're doing seems way too complex for what it's supposed to do..

edit: i editted my answer after user commented:

```
 public bool Login(String uName, String pasw)
{
    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        string oString = "Select ID from yourTable where username = @username AND paswoord = @password";
        SqlCommand oCmd = new SqlCommand(oString, myConnection);
        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", uName);
        oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", pasw);
        string id = null;
        myConnection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
        {              
            while (oReader.Read())
            {
                id = oReader["id"].ToString();
            }
            myConnection.Close();
        }
        if (id == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }         
    }
}
```

you could try something like this. Also, it might have nothing to do with it, but some databases dont like it when you name an attribute "password", you could try changing it to "pw" or "pasw" or whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your response! could you be more specific with what the overall code will look like, i am slightly confused by the //more sql stuff etc.. sorry for my noobishness!

Comment: i editted my answer. if you do it like this, all you have to do is call the method login with the needed parameters. like this: bool validInfo = login(TextBoxUserName.Text,TextBoxPassword.Text); you can then check wheter or not validInfo is true or not.

Comment: there is an error in the line:  using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
'the name ConnString does not exist in the current context'

Comment: well ofcourse that's an error, you have to use your own connectionstring..
 SqlConnection connString = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
paste this line above 
using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connString))

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection to string
thanks for the help so far!

Comment: String connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

try this one. put it above the using (sqlConnection ) ... line.

Comment: it is now telling me 'invalid column name ID' but i dont know where it is referring to, i have tried changing id in the line:  id = oReader["id"].ToString(); but it makes no difference

Comment: do you have a column in your database named "ID" ? just change it to a column name that exists in your database. if i look at the code you've provide you could change it to "Password". so id = oReader["password"] and in the select clause just do select password from table ..

Answer (score 1):

Use [ASP.NET Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx) instead.